# Return many files with json from backend to client

Tags: node.js, express, file, nestjs, multer

I want to know may i respond to client from backend controller with many files (with application/octet-stream). It will be more better, if i respond array of files with json data (for example: user data (nickname, email) with his collection of images in the same response).
So frontend can send json + several files to backend. Can i do the same thing back?

After research i found only information about opportunities to respond application\json and the only file separately (in different requests and responces).

I use nestjs. Nestjs wraps multer lib for handling multipart\form-data.

Of course, there is way to use base64 for files, but i found that better way for files is to use content-type.

Comment: Found 'form-data' lib that allows to send response from backend like frontend sends request to backend. 
[Lib usage article](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2022/how-to-download-multiple-files-javascript/) [lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data)